# Is there a --remote option for vim (not gVim) in cygwin?

Tags: vim, cygwin

I am trying to open a file in a new tab in an already running console Vim session. This functionality is [available in gVim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Launch_files_in_new_tabs_under_Windows) via the `--remote-tab-silent` option.

If this is not possible, is there a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Vim compiled with +clientserver, and you run Cygwin's X server, and you invoke console Vim with a --servername argument, then yes.  See:

```
:help clientserver
:help --servername
```

Example:

```
vim --servername vim
vim --remote-tab-silent foo
```

When you install Cygwin's version of gVim, it should create a symbolic link from /bin/vim to /usr/bin/gvim, which means you will have +clientserver and you can use this functionality in console vim.

The reason the X server is required is that "Unix" variants of Vim use X's security protocols and interprocess communication to implement the +clientserver features. The question is whether you want to have to run Cygwin's X server just to get this functionality.

Comment: Incidentally, I prefer to start Cygwin's X server with the -internalwm argument, which prevents X from running in a window where X clients display; instead, the X clients are handled by Windows' directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am curious how you figured this one out?

Comment: It's not a simple explanation, but part of it is that I follow the Vim developers' mailing list, so I was aware that console Vim could become a server provided an X server was available and the --servername argument was provided on invocation.  It wasn't a stretch to assume that it'd basically be the same under Cygwin as long as Cygwin's X server was available.

Comment: How would I compile it that way ?

Comment: Edit the Makefile and add the line `CONF_OPT_X = --with-x` and uncomment `CONF_OPT_AUTOSERVE = --enable-autoservername`. Then you must run Cygwin's X server. I start it this way: `C:\cygwin64\bin\XWin.exe -multiwindow` Make sure your DISPLAY environment variable is set: `export DISPLAY=:0.0`