# Vimserver on Cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

Following to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/460477/is-there-a-remote-option-for-vim-not-gvim-in-cygwin), I discovered that I can use `--servername <name>` and `--remote` on my console vim executable under Cygwin.

So I installed `vim-common` `vim` and `gvim` and I do not have such options in `/bin/vim`. There are only available with `/bin/gvim`. Unfortunately I do not want to use the `gvim` version of `vim`.

I thought the problem was that vim was not build with the X support. So I built Vim from scratch with `./configure --with-x`. This does not change anything.

How can I use vim server on the console version of Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure libX11-devel and libXt-devel are installed. If your installation of cygwin is up to date, you might have to patch src/mbyte.c to compile Vim 7.4 with +clientserver and +X11.

**check libX11-devel and libXt-devel**

```sh
# vim configure log
#$ grep X_LIB src/auto/config.log
GUI_X_LIBS=''
X_LIB='-lXt -lX11'
X_LIBS=' '

# cygwin
#$ cygcheck.exe -c | grep libX11-devel
libX11-devel                            1.6.3-1                          OK
#$ cygcheck.exe -c | grep libXt-devel
libXt-devel                             1.1.4-2                          OK
```

**Apply Lech Lorens src/mbyte.c patch**

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/OJjnbKQ7oYU

```sh
diff --git a/src/mbyte.c b/src/mbyte.c
 index 6340992..cb14a25 100644
--- a/src/mbyte.c
+++ b/src/mbyte.c
@@ -83,10 +83,18 @@
 # ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
 #  define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
 # endif
-# include <windows.h>
+# if defined(FEAT_GUI) || defined(FEAT_XCLIPBOARD)
+#  include <X11/Xwindows.h>
+#  define WINBYTE wBYTE
+# else
+#  include <windows.h>
+#  define WINBYTE BYTE
+# endif
 # ifdef WIN32
 #  undef WIN32     /* Some windows.h define WIN32, we don't want that here. */
 # endif
+#else
+# define WINBYTE BYTE
 #endif

 #if (defined(WIN3264) || defined(WIN32UNIX)) && !defined(__MINGW32__)
@@ -698,7 +706,7 @@ codepage_invalid:
        /* enc_dbcs is set by setting 'fileencoding'.  It becomes a Windows
     * CodePage identifier, which we can pass directly in to Windows
     * API */
-       n = IsDBCSLeadByteEx(enc_dbcs, (BYTE)i) ? 2 : 1;
+       n = IsDBCSLeadByteEx(enc_dbcs, (WINBYTE)i) ? 2 : 1;
 #else
 # if defined(MACOS) || defined(__amigaos4__)
    /*
```

**compile Vim 7.4 +clientserver +X11**

```sh
#$./configure --with-x
#$ make
#$ ./src/vim.exe --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 

Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title

+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11

#$ ./src/vim.exe --serverlist
TEST
```

Comment: Good point. I was missing `libXt-devel`. Now I have `+X11` with my Vim. Unfortunately I still did not finished the game. If I start a session with `./vim --servername foo` and in another term I test `./vim --serverlist` I don't see the `foo` server. My X-server is running and I can execute `xeyes` on both terminals.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a properly compiled instance of Vim, you have to run the cygwin X server. I have mine set to start when I log in to my Windows machine, with the command line:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\XWin.exe -multiwindow
```

Then I make sure I have DISPLAY set in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0; export DISPLAY
```

This has the added benefit that I can use cygwin's gVim, although I tend to prefer a native Windows gVim instance.

Comment: Done. I've added this to my startup's script. I always did `startxwin&` before without knowing what I was doing...